# Wireshark - On which interface a packet arrived?

Tags: network-programming, wireshark, tcpdump

Does anybody know how can I find out what's the interface a packet arrived on? I captured packets with tcpdump using "-i any" and now I want to find out on what interface a certain packet was received.
And another question, can I start tcpdump on an interface that does not exist yet? The code I am testing creates an interface and starts sending packets imediately. The problem is that by the time I get to hit tcpdump, some packets are already sent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we cannot do that on a interface which is not in network .. we can work on packets which flies in the network so the Ethernet should be in network

Comment: I solved the problem in a different manner. I made a script that checked in a while loop if the interface has been created. Once the interface is created, I started the capture. This is the script, if anybody needs it:
while [ -n $(ifconfig | grep interface)]
do
 usleep 1
done
tcpdump -i interface -s 0 -w ~/capture.cap